# ajax-loaded script not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code below is loaded via ajax:

```
<div class="main">
    //some content
</div>    
<div class="advanced">
    //some content
</div>
<div class="other">
    //some content
</div>
<div class="pass">
    //some content
</div>
<script>$('.advanced,.other,.pass').hide();</script>
```

They hide fine when loaded normally, but when loaded via ajax it doesn't work anymore. Why is it so? I'm not really sure if `$.on()` would really help here.

Comment: @Adil the OP tagged jQuery, isn't that obvious?

Comment: $.on() is for binding event handler so it's not the problem here, which function are you using to do your AJAX call? if doing via jquery it more than likely get stripped out so you need to do it from the caller page.

Comment: @Joseph, plenty of websites use Ajax.Net in combination with jQuery, not as obvious as you make out.

Comment: @BrianScott but if the OP did use Ajax.Net, then he should have tagged it also, *but he didn't*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the example above is loaded via jQuery ajax, why not just call the

> $('.advanced,.other,.pass').hide();

upon completion of the ajax request?

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Your AJAX URL",
    dataType: 'html',
    type: "POST",
    success: function (json) {
        // Add you elements to the DOM
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('.advanced,.other,.pass').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This applies to many views I have (MVC). That would fairly increase the number of lines (like that) on the script when they're not currently used/needed.

Comment: @Jack, create a common.js, define the call as a function once and reuse it when required.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> any embedded JavaScript inside the retrieved data *is executed before the HTML is returned as a string.*

this could mean that your script executed first, before you managed to do anything with it.

Comment: I tried wrapping them in `$(function(){ /* hide */ });` but it didn't hide them.